# PyQt5 inside virtualenv doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, installation, pyqt5

I have installed a PyQt5 inside a virtual env follow the steps: (Windows)

1 - Download a sip and PyQt whl files from source

2 - Open a administrator prompt

3 - Activate virtual env

4 - pip install sip "path_sip_whl_file"

5 - pip install PyQt5 "path_sip_whl_file"

Apparently the procedure was sucessful

But when i try to execute command:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

Returns me error:

"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

I need some more thing?

Thanks a lot!
Felipe Fonseca